# Input cell from another sheet based on named cell name

Tags: google-sheets

Is they a simple way to import a cell from another sheet based on the name of a cell in the current sheet?

Below, I trying to say if A2 equals named sheet say Sheet2 then import J10 from Sheet2

```
=IMPORTRANGE(""=A2"","J10")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using =indirect("'"&A2&"'!J10")